# Difference between layout:column and layout:columnSpan

Tags: java, android

I can't found in doc, what is difference between `layout_column` and `layout_columnSpan` in `TextView`.
Could someone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**layout_column** is the column index of your TextView in your layout while **layout_columnSpan** is the number of columns your TextView spans (*The difference between the right and left boundaries delimiting the group of cells occupied by this view.*).